# Google Scholar intitle and OR search combination

Tags: google-scholar

I would like to use the following type of search in Google Scholar:

> virtual reality and retention intitle:"Visual cues" OR "cueing" OR "signal" OR "signalling"

Thus, I want to search for Google Scholar entries that have "Visual cues" OR "cueing" OR "signal" OR "signalling" in their title. However, this search does not seem to work as intended as it leads to more than 40,000 results which clearly do not all include the keywords in the title: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=virtual+reality+and+retention+intitle%3A%22Visual+cues%22+OR+%22cueing%22+OR+%22signal%22+OR+%22signalling%22&btnG=.

Is there a different syntax to achieve my desired search?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I think the intitle keyword only applies to "Visual cues" in your search.

Comment: What part is "virtual reality and retention" in your search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`virtual reality and retention  intitle:"Visual cues" OR intitle:"cueing" OR intitle:"signal" OR intitle:"signalling"`